# How to find roots of polynomial $a z \overline{z} + \overline{b}z + b \overline{z}+c$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $a,c \in \mathbb R$ and $b \in \mathbb C$ with $|b|^2 - ac > 0$. I am stuck trying to find roots of the polynomial  $a z \overline{z} + \overline{b}z + b \overline{z}+c$. I know the formula for quadratic polynomials but since this polynomial seems to be of two variables $z$ and $\overline{z}$ it does not apply.

> How to find the roots of the polynomial $a z \overline{z} + \overline{b}z + b
>  \overline{z}+c$?

Comment: Maybe you can try to find why the condition is expressed as $|b|^2 - ac$ and not $|b|^2 - 4de$. Maybe try to set $d=a/2$ and $e = c/2$? Try to express $z$ and $b$ in polar coordinates and solve equations for module and phase separately? Just some thoughts.

Comment: Ok, solved it. Hint : What are the conditions (in polar coordinates) for a complex number to be equal to zero?

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA Why "in polar coordinates"? The number is zero if and only if its absolute value is zero... no?

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA So to solve this I should calculate the absolute value of the polynomial?

Comment: try to set $z = \rho e^{i\theta}$ and b as $b = \rho_b e^{i\theta_b}$, and try to solve the equations on $\rho$ and $\theta$.